# Typescript: Understanding how the pieces fit - typings, @typings, tsc and DefinitelyTypes

Tags: typescript, typing, tsc

Am I getting this right?

**tsc**

---

Its the typescript cli tool and the global version running on my machine.

**typings**

---

[typings](https://github.com/typings/typings) is a few things. A cli tool to install **.d.ts** files into your project AND the folder that save to inside my project.

**For example:**

you can search for **.d.ts** scripts by running:

```
typings search foo
```

and add a package:

```
typings install --global --save dt~foo
```

then have the `typings/index.d.ts` reference all my `.d.ts` definition files

```
/// <reference path="globals/foo/index.d.ts" />
```

Then if I wanted to use `foo` anywhere in my project I could add

```
 declare var foo: any;
 import foo from "foo";
```

**Definitely Types**

---

**Definitely Types** files have a **.d.ts** extension that allow javascript methods to be called in Typescript

**@typings**

---

Is a folder located at `node_modules/@typings` and is the same as the `typings` folder, but are installed by running `npm install @typings/foo` and not `typings install foo`.

---

My questions are:

1. why are there two different ways to install typings do this? Is the first method a depreciated method of including **Definitely Types** files to my project?
2. Are `@typings` module still searchable by running?

   typings search foo
3. How are I make my project aware of my `typings`, did defining them like `/// <reference path="globals/foo/index.d.ts" />` get scrapped?
4. Do I always/when do I declare my **.d.ts** files in my project like `declare var foo: any;`
5. Do you still need to use the `ambient` or `global` flags when installing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a little confusing for me as well as I've spent the last couple months familiarizing with TypeScript...

**tsc**

Correct, this is the **T**ype**S**cript **C**ompiler which translates your files to JavaScript.

**Typings**

Typings is a cli TypeScript definitions manager which allows you to manage (search, install, uninstall, etc.) definition files (*.d.ts) for JavaScript libraries from a variety of sources.

**DefinitelyTyped**

DefinitelyTyped is a repository of definition files which is one of the sources that Typings allows you to gather/manage files from.

**npm @types**

The good news is with latest release of TypeScript (version 2.0+) you no longer need to use a manager and/or worry about which repositories to gather files from. All of the definitions from DefinitelyTyped are now available to install via *npm* (example: `npm install @types/knockout --save`).

Using this method will download the definition file, save the dependency in your *project.json* file (if the --save flag is specified) which TypeScript then automatically looks for the definition whenever you `require()` the module within your code (you no longer need to use `/// <reference />` if you use this method).

---

The [TypeScript website](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) has pretty extensive documentation on project setup and [how to use tsconfig.json](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) files to properly setup your application for compilation with or without definition files.

Comment: thank you for taking the time to answer this. Do you happen to know my questions 4 & 5 as well?

Comment: 4) Referencing definition files with the [triple slash directives](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html) is no longer needed for third part JavaScript installed via npm. This is because the @types folder is considered visible to the compiler.

Comment: For declaration files you create for internal modules, simply putting them in the same folder or in a parent folder the compiler will pick it up. However Its recommended to use a tsconfig.json which allows for specifying globs (ex: src/**/*) which will tell the compiler to include all supported typescript files.

Comment: 5) You no longer need to specify the "global" flag when installing typings with npm as all external typings are now considered global. As for "ambient" I'm not certain but I think this as well is no longer needed.

The [documentation on module resolution](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#node) should help with most of your questions.